# UILabel to show 1k for int value 1000 and 2k for 2000 and so on

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, nsnumberformatter

I have `UILabel` in which `int` value is shown, I want that if value is in thousand like 1000 then label should show 1k and 2k for 2000 and onward. How can this be achieved?

Comment: @Wain: I tried to use NSNumberFormatter but in vain.

Comment: what you want for 2345? 2.3 K or 2K or 2.345K?

Comment: @MugheesMusaddiq : post what you have tried...

Comment: @Fahim: It should be 2.3K for 2345

Comment: @Fahim: Let me check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
int myNum = 12345;
NSLog(@"%.1f K", myNum/1000);
```

Comment: That is not bad for the formating itself. but creates a blank between the number and the K.

Comment: If you want to round it to the first decimal point. you could use:
    
`round(10 * myNum) / 10`

Comment: @HermannKlecker : `creates a blank between the number and the K` are you talking about space?

Comment: What about small numbers, like 12, how will it be displayed?

Comment: @Thomas : Boss, if you start checking everything then I have to add check whether this is integer or not, then it should be greater then 999, then round and what not... Right? Here we don't answer ***detailed answer***. *With my answer, OP get what he wanted.*

Answer (score 1):

Extension that allows format numbers into words -> 1.000 = 1K 1.500 -> 1.5K 1.000.000 -> 1M. 
Usage: myInt.abbreviateNumber()

```
extension Int {
    func abbreviateNumber() -> String {
        if self < 1000 {
            return "\(self)"
        }

        if self < 1000000 {
            var n = Double(self);
            n = Double( floor(n/100)/10 )
            return "\(n.description)K"
        }

        var n = Double(self)
        n = Double( floor(n/100000)/10 )
        return "\(n.description)M"
    }
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/Dfmarulanda/f575a7088811b6a0759a

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, or three even.

1st 
You do this programmatically before you set the value in the label.

2nd 
You extend UILabel by a setter for the int value which does the formatting and sets the appropriate string value.

3rd
You subclass UILabel and add a setter for int values. That does the formatting and sets the appropriate string. 
Extending is a bit less work but subclassing allows for overwriting the regular setter so that you can throw an exception or whatever you want.

All three have one thing in common: You will have to do the formatting programmatically. (int division by 1000 and then use a regular string format)

Extending or subclassing `UILabel` makes the solution reusable.